# Android Studio IDE shows error on old dependencies but compiles and runs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I updated Android Studio gradle and compile SDK versions a few days ago in my project. Since then, the IDE started to show "Cannot resolve symbol 'Request'" on Volley and all old dependencies in the project but it still run correctly.

The problem is that it's annoying to see all my code in red when it's not having any error.

I'll show you my gradle files below:

app.gradle

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myproject.android"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }
}
dependencies {
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.8@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.1.0'
}
```

project.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: May be you forget to tell about error?

Comment: @Khemraj yes, sorry. I updated the post, IDE shows 'Cannot resolve symbol [any Class of an old dependency, eg: volley.Request]'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Cannot+resolve+symbol+%27Request%27

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a problem on my gradle build. I just deleted .gradle folder and rebuilt project to solve it.